# Is there a custom module to drag and drop files in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

There is an option in Drupal 7 to drag and drop files (https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload). But couldn't find one for Drupal 8. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 drag and drop files feature is possible using the PLupload (https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) and PLUPload Widget (https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload_widget) combination. Provides integration between for the Plupload widget to upload multiple files and Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I also search for this but not found any module for that.
You need to do it by custom by using any third party library.

E.g: you can use [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) library, they have good documentation also.

Answer (score 0):

Work is being done directly in Drupal 8 core.  All efforts should be directed there so that contrib/custom modules are not necessary for this purpose.

See [File Field design update](https://www.drupal.org/node/2113931) for details.